# Finding a divisibility test for $2^j$ for all j greater than or equal to 3.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I attempted doing this case by case for $2,3,4,..,9$ however if anyone has structured way of solving it, it would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "divisibility test"?  There are some nice structured ways to handle it, depending on what you're trying to do...

Comment: Much easier in binary :)

Comment: Getting at @ThomasAndrews comment, it seems you are assuming the number is presented in standard base-10 representation, and you're looking for a rule in terms of the digits?

Comment: Well, I need to do the divisibility tests on all number written as 2^j given j is greater than or equal to 3. For example 2 divides 2^j, then I would need to show why 3 doesn't divide 2^j etc up to 9.

Comment: @Samir You mean you want to know what $2^j$ is divisible **by**, rather than what $2^j$ **divides**?  That's easy: since $2$ is prime, the only divisors of $2^j$ are $2^i$ for $0 \le i \le j$.

Comment: hmm that's the result I got by doing it case by case, but can you prove it using modulo arithmetic or any other formal way? thanks

Comment: @Samir $2^j$ is for all $j>1$ divisible by only one prime number which is 2. This should be obvious. I hope this was not your question.

Answer (score 2):

For very large numbers or small $j$ just go with the usual, a number is divisible by $2^j$ if the last $j$ digits are divisible by $2^j$

Comment: it can be less than "j digits"

Comment: @Agawa001 Put zeros in front. Every number has potentially infinitely many digits if you allow zeroes in front.

Answer (score 0):

- The rule of congruence is blatantly needed here:

Checkability of $2^1$:

first digit:  $\ \ \ \ \ 2, 4, 6, 8 ,0$

second digit: $ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1$

the process is cyclic and first digit must be even

---

Checkability of $2^2$:

first digit:$\ \ \ \ \   4, 8, 2, 6 ,0 $

second digit: $ 0, 0, 1, 1, 2$

the process is cyclic and first digit in addition that it must be even, second digit is related to divisibility of first digit by 4.

---

Checkability of $2^3$:

first digit:$\ \ \ \ \   8, 6, 4, 2 ,0 $

second digit: $ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$

the process is cyclic and first digit in addition that it must be even, second digit $Sec$ is related to first digit $Fir$, as $Fir=|(2*Sec)\mod 5-8|/2$.

...

I think it isnt transcendental as we move on ...

Answer (score 0):

The standard method taught in school is

> A number is divisible by $2^n$ if the last $n$ digits are.

Here is another good one:

> If  the first digit is even, examine the number formed by the last $n-1$ digits.
>   If the first digit is odd, examine the number formed by the last $n-1$ digits plus $2^{n-1}$.